# OpenCV basic tutorial

Tags: iphone, ios, opencv

I am a new in iPhone Application development, I wants to use OpenCV in my project. I am googling from last few hour, but not find the start up  tutorial for OpenCV mostly links explain the advance programming, So I need help

please provide me good tutorial link for starter.

Comment: I know c, c++, objective-c  but first time integrate openCV in my Xcode project.

Answer (score 8):

https://github.com/BloodAxe/opencv-ios-template-project

http://computer-vision-talks.com/2011/08/a-complete-ios-opencv-sample-project/

http://maniacdev.com/2011/08/open-source-sample-project-using-precompiled-opencv-2-3-1/

Answer (score 2):

here you find good documentation of opencv

- opencv [site](http://opencv.willowgarage.com)
- opencv [docs](http://docs.opencv.org)
- [eosgarden](http://www.eosgarden.com/en/opensource/opencv-ios/documentation/tutorial/)
- List of tutorials in [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5739247/1225337)

Answer (score 2):

Here are some links from stackoverflow itself . Please check them out :-

[Tutorial for iPhone OpenCV on shape recognising](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738792/tutorial-for-iphone-opencv-on-shape-recognising)

http://www.eosgarden.com/en/opensource/opencv-ios/documentation/tutorial/

http://computer-vision-talks.com/2011/08/a-complete-ios-opencv-sample-project/