# Regarding openCV in ios Application

Tags: iphone

i am new in using openCv library for image processing in iOS application, through which i wanna make image with changing contrast, brightness using slider.i mean when we slide the slider image should be increase contrast or brightness as well.
Please provide me some link , and also tell the the steps to use this library in iOS Application.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What language/framework are you using?

Comment: i am using objective-c language with ios 7 in xcode 5

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889419/opencv-basic-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

First you need to start getting familar with openCV follow this tutorial, I tried it before:

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/ios/table_of_content_ios/table_of_content_ios.html

for changing or controlling images using UIControllers you can simply read value of slider using that slider delegate and apply filters on the image, don't forget that openCV deal with Mat of images so you will need first to change your UIImage into cv::Mat.